# Is the characteristic polynomial of a linear transformation T unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Say I have a linear map $T \in L(V)$. There can be multiple bases of $V$ and hence multiple matrices which represent the transformation $T$ in the form of a matrix, if we think of matrices with respect to ordered bases. So it seems to me right now that there can be multiple characteristic polynomials, each corresponding to a particular matrix representation of $T$? And solving each of them should give me the same roots i.e. eigen values? Is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A change of basis corresponds to a conjugation by an invertible matrix (i.e. we consider $PAP^{-1}$ instead of $A$). However, $$\det(PAP^{-1}-tI)=\det(PAP^{-1}-tPP^{-1})=\det(P(A-tI)P^{-1})=\\=\det (P)\det(A-tI)\det(P^{-1})=\det(PP^{-1})\det(A-tI)=\det(A-tI)$$

Comment: Aah yes, this is neat, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial, as @Gae.S.'s answer shows.

However given a matrix, the characteristic polynomial is unique. If the matrix is $A $, one computes $\rm {det}(A-xI) $.

Interesting in this connection is the *Frobenius companion matrix*,  which is *a* matrix having given characteristic polynomial.